# JSON.NET will not convert back to JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a microservices architecture for a solution I am developing using Angularjs, Web Api and DocumentDb. I have a simple controller that takes a json file and returns it as a JObject across the wire... like so...

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Json/" + path + ".json"), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                dtsContent = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(streamReader));
            }
            return new IsoncOkResult<JObject>(dtsContent, this) ;
```

The IsoncOkResult is just my implementation of a IHttpActionResult
The above works with no errors.... 
but when I do this code on the calling service...

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var dtsLookup = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(sr));
```

I get the horribe JsonReader currentitem is not an object error...

I have tried JToken, JArray.... none work... I need to be able to access the returned object in c# like

```
dtsLookup["name"]
```

Or whatever....

The original JSON is...

```
[ {
"name": "1|Identifiers|ShipName",
"flag": "1|Flag",
"ircs": "1|Identifiers|Ircs",
"flag_reg_number": "1|Identifiers|FlagRegNo",
"mmsi": "1|Identifiers|Mmis",
"port_of_registry": "1|Port",
"date_of_flag_registerd": "1|FirstRegDate",
"parallel_registry": "1|HistoricalData|ParallelReg",
"previous_de_registered_date": "1|HistoricalData|PrevDeRegDate",
"ffa_vid": "1|Identifiers|SecondaryId"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [JSON](http://www.json.org/) consists of an array containing a single object:

```
[{"name1" : "value1", ..., "nameN" : "valueN"}]
```

The brackets indicate an array, the nested braces indicate an object.

If you are unsure whether your JSON object will be nested in an array, and just want to get the first object that appears in the JSON, you can do:

```
        var dtsRoot = (JContainer)JToken.Load(new JsonTextReader(sr)); // JContainer is the base class for JArray and JObject
        var dtsLookup = dtsRoot.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().FirstOrDefault();
        var name = (string)dtsLookup["name"];
```

Alternatively, you can use [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) with the `..` recursive descent wildcard to find the value of the first property of a given name that appears anywhere in the JSON document:

```
        var dtsRoot = JToken.Load(new JsonTextReader(sr));
        var name = (string)dtsRoot.SelectToken("..name");
```

`SelectToken` supports [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Comment: Thanks!! That's helped loads!!